# How to create a read only access key for Container Registry Azure

Tags: azure, acr

I'm on the basic account type on Azure.

I have: A private registry with only one Access Key (Admin one)

I want: To be able to create more access keys with read only (acrpull) access.

Question: Am I reading correct from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-skus#sku-feature-matrix that this is not allowed (only in the premium account)?

Isn't there a way to create another token with acrpull access only on a basic account?

Regards,

Comment: you have azure ad?

Comment: No, I don't have

Comment: az ad user list - it is displaying a users so I think I have it acctually - most probably the basic one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, you can. It uses a service principal to do the authentication. You need to create a service principal assigned with the role **acrpull** for the ACR.

Here is an example script which uses the CLI command:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Modify for your environment.
# ACR_NAME: The name of your Azure Container Registry
# SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME: Must be unique within your AD tenant
ACR_NAME=<container-registry-name>
SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME=acr-service-principal

# Obtain the full registry ID for subsequent command args
ACR_REGISTRY_ID=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --query id --output tsv)

# Create the service principal with rights scoped to the registry.
# Default permissions are for docker pull access. Modify the '--role'
# argument value as desired:
# acrpull:     pull only
# acrpush:     push and pull
# owner:       push, pull, and assign roles
SP_PASSWD=$(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name http://$SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME --scopes $ACR_REGISTRY_ID --role acrpull --query password --output tsv)
SP_APP_ID=$(az ad sp show --id http://$SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME --query appId --output tsv)

# Output the service principal's credentials; use these in your services and
# applications to authenticate to the container registry.
echo "Service principal ID: $SP_APP_ID"
echo "Service principal password: $SP_PASSWD"
```

You can get more details in [Azure Container Registry authentication with service principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal), and also you can choose an appropriate role as you need when you take a look at [Azure Container Registry roles and permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles).

Comment: My goodness! Excellent answer, with a minor touchup on the query for the APP ID for me. 

The line works for SP_APP_ID with an updated query as:
`USER_NAME=$(az ad sp list --display-name $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME --query "[].appId" --output tsv)`